# What is the numerical method used in this implementation of IRR?

Tags: python, algorithm, numerical-methods

The [ActiveState Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576686-npv-irr-payback-analysis/?in=user-4169084) site has a function implementing [Internal Rate of Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return) in Python:

```
def irr(cashflows, iterations=100):
    """The IRR or Internal Rate of Return is the annualized effective 
       compounded return rate which can be earned on the invested 
       capital, i.e., the yield on the investment.

       >>> irr([-100.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0])
       0.36309653947517645
    """
    rate = 1.0
    investment = cashflows[0]
    for i in range(1, iterations+1):
        rate *= (1 - npv(rate, cashflows) / investment)
    return rate
```

This code returns correct values (at least for the couple of examples that I have checked against Excel), but I would like to know *why*.

- It doesn't appear to be an implementation of Newton's Method (no derivative) or the Secant Method (only keeps track of one iteration).
- In particular, the definition of the investment variable as the first cashflow element (and it's subsequent use) confuses me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is called fixed point iteration; see for instance the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_iteration.

The idea is that if `rate` contains the correct value (that is, the IRR), then the NPV is zero, so the statement

```
rate *= (1 - npv(rate, cashflows) / investment)
```

will not change `rate`. Thus, once you find the IRR, the iteration will not change it. Fixed point iteration sometimes converges to the correct value and sometimes it does not. The examples of @Gareth and @unutbu show that here it does not always converge.

The criterion for convergence is as follows. Write the update statement in the loop as

```
rate = rate * (1 - npv(rate, cashflows) / investment)
```

Now, if the derivative of the right-hand side with respect to `rate` is between 1 and -1, then the method converges. I cannot immediately see under what circumstances this is the case.

You may wonder why the iteration does not do

```
rate *= (1 - npv(rate, cashflows))
```

without the weird `investment` variable. Indeed, I wondered the same; that would also be a fixed point method that converges to the IRR if the derivative condition is satisfied. My guess is that the derivative condition is satisfied in some circumstances for the method that you gave, and not for the method without `investment`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems bogus to me. The convergence is too slow for practical use.

```
>>> irr([-100, 100]) # expecting answer 0
0.00990099009900991
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems bogus to me, too.

```
>>> irr([-100,50],100000)  # expecting answer -0.5
0.0
```

Comment: I think you are expecting the answer -0.5. (0.5 would be the IRR for the cashflows [-100, 150].) But bogus in any case!